# difference between '-webkit-box-shadow' & 'box-shadow' in css

Tags: css

Recently I have started to learn css here I came to know about

```
box-shadow
```

property in CSS then I came to know another property

```
-webkit-box-shadow:
```

and also

```
-moz-box-shadow:
```

which also used to give shadow to the shadow. I just can't differentiate between them. Can anybody help me to understand exactly this properties?

Thanks in advance to helpers.

Comment: `-webkit` and `-moz` are vendor prefixs for browsers. They are normally for the support of older versions. Whereas without vendor prefix css property is for latest versions(mostly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They all apply a [*box shadow*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow). However, `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow` are specific to Webkit (e.g. Safari) and Mozilla browsers respectively.

As a CSS 3 property, these are used as vendor specific implementations of *box shadow* until it becomes [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow).

Answer (score 1):

`box-shadow` is a CSS3 standart implementation, while other 2 are browser specific (or rather engine specific) implementation for WebKit browsers (e.g. Chrome) or Gecko browsers (e.g. FireFox)

Answer (score 1):

They are, essentially all the same. However it is for each browser to pick up, as they do not all fall into line by just picking up box-shadow property

For a full article on the pitfalls and plusses: [Vendor-specific Properties](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vendorspecific)